# How to project display via WiFi to Epson BrightLink projector?

Tags: wifi, display

My workplace has an Epson BrightLink projector. The device is connected to the workplace WiFi. On Windows, one can install the Epson iProjection software, which allows me to type in the projector's IP address. I was able to project from the desktop to the display with a HDMI cable, but this is hazardous, people can easily trip on the cord.

Is there a solution for projecting from my Linux computer to this device, also via WiFi?